# problem with dom createelement and innerhtml

Tags: javascript, dom

```
/*************** javascript *****************/

function here(getValue) {

    alert(getValue)
}

function aaa() {

    document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="textfield" onkeyup="here(this.value)" />'
}

function aaa2() {

    var temp = document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML
    document.getElementById('asd').innerHTML = temp+'<input type="text" name="textfield" onkeyup="here(this.value)" />'
}

function dom() {

    var zzz = document.getElementById('asd')

    var inp = document.createElement('input')
    inp.type = 'text'
    inp.name = 'textfield'
    inp.onkeyup = function() {here(this.value)}

    zzz.appendChild(inp)
}

/************************************/

<div id="asd"> 
    <input type="text" name="textfield" onkeyup="here(this.value)" />
</div>

<input type="button" name="Button1" value="Button1" onclick="aaa2()" />
<input type="button" name="Button2" value="Button2" onclick="dom()" />
```

need some help...

i create a textfield using dom by click Button1, then combine with textfield using innerhtml by click button2.

the problem is after combine the dom createelement with innerhtml, the textfield created by dom cannot call the javascript function...

anyone have a solution...

thanks...

Comment: I strongly suggest you edit your question - I tried but I can't make sense of it to edit it

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code as to how it works (maybe not best practices, but it works).

Tested and working in firefox 3.5. See test page at http://ashita.org/StackOverflow/innerhtml.html

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this

```
inp.onkeyup = function() {here(this.value)}
```

You can't define onkeyup like this if it didn't existed before. Plus, this argument must be a string (basically, the Javascript code to execute)

```
inp.setAttribute('onkeyup','here(this.value)');
```